# How to access java script value in jsp?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I created an input text box and set its value through jquery.

```
<input type="text" name="policy" id="policyIdSelected" />

$("#policyIdSelected").val(policyId);
```

The value is shown in the text box. But when i tried to access the input value in the same jsp using "policy", I am not getting it.

Please help me on this.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. Be specific: what code are you running, what's it supposed to do, what does it actually do.

Comment: [jsp] runs on the server, [javascript] runs on the client.

Comment: do a simple task set js value in session using ajax and access this value anywhere in your session :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the form data first before using input field's value in the JSP because JSP code has already been ran in the server side.
But, you can keep accessing or changing value in client side using js.